# How to fix that not working jquery code in VScode

Tags: jquery, html, visual-studio-code

I've recently started using visual studio code (VScode) and I got a issue with running code on the web browser.When I code jquery into the html file, every syntax is recognized by ide and seems good but those functions don't work on the pages in the browser.Also do I need any more extension for installing or not?

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors on the console?

Comment: How did you include jQuery in html file? Can't see it in screenshot

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: jquery code is in the script tag

Comment: Please also add your code as text, rather than an image, it makes it easier for people to try to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include `jQuery` in your file.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Works for me once I include this.

Answer (score 0):

just gone through your code... The source file mean where you pulling your jquery from isn't written correctly... Check your code very well... You typed in scritp instead of script...

Comment: that's ok with filename and src link is correct and also it is for javascript code.